# PHP : POST-- How to replace defined KEY from ARRAY in a file

Tags: php, post, flat-file

I'm a bit lost for I'm "green" in PHP.

Please, may you teach me how to fix this:

on 'POST' --> Replace a specified array key from a file:

(WRONG:)

```
<?php
    $newData = $_POST["sendData"]; 

    if(isset($_POST['sendData'])){

        $file = fopen('fileToOpen.php', 'a');

        foreach($file as $key => $val) 
        {
            $data[$key] = explode("|", $val);
        }

        for($k = 0; $k < sizeof($file); $k++)
        {
            unset($data[$k][3]);
        }

        $data[$k][3] = "$newData";
        fwrite($file, $data[$k][3]);
        fclose ($file);

    }
?>
```

That's wrong as it continues to write:

data1|data2|data3|**oldDatanewData**

instead of rewrite:

data1|data2|data3|**newData**

Is there any other technique to achieve something similar? Perhaps with `file_put_contents`? Am I missing `implode`?

Thanks!

Comment: First thought: Writing `user-submitted data` to a `.php` file is just ASKING to get hacked.

Comment: `fopen` returns a resource and resources cannot be used with foreach. Raise your error_reporting!

Comment: @jnpcl Thanks for your concern, That IS an **Admin** option for I've written a secured login with **md5** and so on... This is an admin choice that has to be written to a fl.fi. database, to be lately reused. :)

Comment: @roXon: Even so, it's probably smarter to use a different file extension, and block the file from non-script access. **Scenario:** Your Admin login cookie gets hijacked, and even though your server/hosting/ftp login is different, the attacker now has a way to write to a `.php` file on your server.

Comment: @jnpcl Interesting. I'm low about hijacking. But I have created a temporary file on the server. On admin LOGIN (if the entered username and password are correct) the admin IP is stored (md5) into a file. So no cookies are set. Is that a good way?

Comment: @roXoN: Are you using PHP sessions?

Comment: @jnpcl No, I do not use php sessions. The admin sends to the server USERNAME and PASSW(-->md5). the server than says: "aham, if UN & PW == UN & PW... than OK! grab the user IP(--> md5) and write it to a file! So the admin is always logged cause at any page refresh or any changes his IP is stored! :)    I'm planning to add to the IP some other data... as the computer name or whatever I can grab :| Is that fine?... What you think?

Comment: @roXon: If you're ONLY using the IP address to verify continued access after login, then all it would take is somebody on the same network to visit your admin page after you've logged in.

Comment: @jnpcl I'm aware of that, as my girlfriend can login from an other PC on the same network if I do not LOGOUT. What other exclusive data can I grab from the PC to be stored? Have you an idea? (And... do you think is the concept ok?)

Comment: @roXon: Anything that's sent from the client can be faked. Proper authentication can be rather complex, but I think we're getting a bit beyond the scope of your question. At the **very least**, write to a file extension (such as `.txt`) that isn't going to get parsed and executed by your server.

Comment: @jnpcl (hehe, you are right!) That's an awesome point of view. As till now I was sure that is easier to get a index-of: and see the .txt fine right on screen as a text file, and on the other side, that was harder to get an array included into PHP tags, for all the codes inside <?php are executed on server. So now I'm interested on how is more secure with .txt, and how to hide this txt from being displayed! (htaccess?)

Comment: @roXon: Yup, `.htaccess` can be used to prevent access to files. You could also store the file outside of your `www` directory, so the ONLY way to access it is through the server's filesystem.

Comment: @jnpcl Wow! Thanks! I'll keep all this conversation and suggestions in mind!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dunno what are you asking for but perhaps you only need to serialize and unserialize the array.

```
$data_array = unserialize(file_get_contents('fileToOpen.php'));
$data_array[$key_you_want_to_change] = $new_data;
file_put_contents('fileToOpen.php', serialize($data_array));
```

Comment: I don't think the submitter's file is in `serialize()` format, but the `file_get_contents`/`file_put_contents` part is right.

Comment: @aaz & @marines Correct, I want to explode the line by '|' into keys. Now found the 3th key : replace it (OVERWRITE IT) with posted data!

Comment: I assume roXon will save serialized array in the file before reading it. :)

Comment: Good point. @roXon, `serialize()`/`unserialize()` is more robust if you can pick the format. If not, just replace that with `implode('|', ...)`/`explode('|', ...)`.

Comment: @aaz @marines It works!!! with `explode('|')` / `implode('|', ...)` like you said! Thanks you all! I was doing it wrong: `$data_array[3] = explode( file_get_contents('|', $fileName));`  CORRECT: `$data_array[3] = explode('|', file_get_contents($fileName));` !!!  :)

Answer (score 0):

$newData = $_POST['sendData'];

```
 if(isset($_POST['sendData'])){

 $file = "fileToOpen.php";
```

$oldData = file_get_contents($file);

$oldData = eregi_replace("\n","",$oldData);

$FullDataArray = explode("?",$oldData);
$oldDataArray = explode("|",$FullDataArray[1]);

$oldDataArray[3] = $newData;

$newDataString .= "

foreach($oldDataArray as $key=>$val) {

$newDataString .= $val;

if($key!="3") {

$newDataString .= "|";
 }

}

$fh = fopen($file, 'w');

fwrite($fh,$newDataString);

fclose($fh);

}

?>

Comment: This erase the whole line from the file. :( I need only the 3th arr to overwrite. :| 
I'm trYing to adapt the code above but still unsuccessfully.