# How to: overwrite defined array with new POSTED data

Tags: php, arrays, replace, key, overwrite

I'll redefine my old unanswered & messy [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5022700/php-post-how-to-replace-defined-key-from-array-in-a-file/5023080#5023080) 'cause i'm begging for Your help. Anyone...

I have a line inside a file (choices.php) that has:

```
some choice1...||other choice2...||some data here...||OVERWRITE ME! I AM OLD!
```

On an other page there is a **button** that **POST** (and store/save) new data into choices.php. This NewData have to **overwrite** some text ($arrkey[3])

I tried `explode` / `implode`, `file_put_contents`, anything I've found browsing for answers. But the far I could get was the NewData being just ADDED at the end of that line:

**some choice1...||other choice2...||some data here...||OVERWRITE ME! I AM OLD!I'M THE NEW DATA!**

instead of:

**some choice1...||other choice2...||some data here...||I'M THE NEW DATA!**

Comment: Please specify what you want exactly by defining "my current text" and "my expected text"

Comment: @Maulik : I assume you want to suggest the use of str_replace ? I actually have a 'toggle' button that toggles texts: **NOTIFY:ON** and **NOTIFY:OFF**

Comment: @roxon no bro, I want to understand exact question and your requirement. so that I can suggest best answer.

Comment: @Maulik  I was editing the comment above! (Thanks in advance)

Comment: ok so you want 'some choice1...||other choice2...||some data here...||I'M THE NEW DATA!' instead of 'some choice1...||other choice2...||some data here...||OVERWRITE ME! I AM OLD!', sorry but can you also tell me this text is stored in 'file' or in any 'php-variable'?

Comment: @Maulik I shake-hands you for all your time, Maulik, I have the answer. Check out! Bye

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I got your question right, the following code will do what you want :

```
$entries = explode('||', file_get_contents('choices.php'));
$entries[3] = $_POST['myfield']; // You may want to do more strict checking before that.
file_put_contents('choices.php', implode('||', $entries));
```

And, by the way, choices.php is a bad name, since the file doesn't actually contain any PHP code. But it's won't prevent the script from working.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and suggestion. I'm on my way with the TEST :) I'll make you know the results!

Comment: You should see my happy tears now! It's 9 hours i'm trying to figure that out! I thank you soo much!!! btw. heheh my last try on screen was: `$arrNum = explode( file_get_contents('||', $fileName));` ...close but... far far far :)  THANKS SOOOO MUCH!